# Start neo4j server with other configuration file

Tags: neo4j

I try to start neo4j on OSX and change the chosen configuration file. I'd like to start a test server for unit tests with a different port and a database, which shall be deleted while startup (I will solve the deletion part in a shell script, which should stop and start the server).

My problem is neo4j ignores the configuration file from the parameter. My call looks like this (from the  terminal and the current folder is bin:

```
./neo4j start -server -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server-test.properties
```

The default configuration file is still chosen.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no 'ad hoc' arguments to the neo4j command script, so your arguments after start are ignored. You need to either make a modified version of the neo4j command script, or swap out neo4j-server.properties files.

Comment: But why do they print out:
`Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xms1024m -     Xmx4096m
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user`

after  `./neo4j start`

Comment: It's informational. Only the Neo4j guys know exactly why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ineo to manage two or more Neo4j instances:

https://github.com/cohesivestack/ineo

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path to a folder containing a customized configuration file with an environment variable:

`NEO4J_CONF=../conf neo4j start`